# Is it possible to change the create_time of a MySQL MYISAM table?

Tags: mysql

I have a program that uses the table create time (as reported by information_schema.tables.create_time) in its logic.

For testing, I want to be able to create tables that appear to have been created in the past (to exercise those code paths.)

I have tried changing the mtime of the .frm file, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  (If I change the mtime of the .MYD file, it changes the update_time.)  Also, `stat -c '%w'` just reports `-` (unknown) for the "birth time" of the .frm file.

I have also tried looking in the .frm file contents (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html) and didn't see anything there.

Anyone know where MySQL stores the create_time?  Obviously it's stored somewhere!

Edit: It looks like maybe it's part of the state structure in the MYI file?  (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/the-myi-file.html)

Comment: You should install ``MyAdmin`` and then can import complete database there. And then you can simply change date values fron UI interface.

Comment: Do you mean phpMyAdmin?  (phpmyadmin.net)  If so, in their demo, I don't even see where I could see table create time, not to mention how to change it.
Any help or clarification?
Thanks.